# Loadrunner - share common action between scripts

Tags: c, performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

Is there a clever way to share common actions between scripts in Loadrunner?

Let me explain. Our company will have to create 50 different scripts with different scenarios. Most of them requires logging on to our website, and logging out. It's kind of annoying to have to update 50 scripts, when the log-in requests are changed. Can this be created once, and be used by all the other scripts?

Using C-language, Web - http, Loadrunner 11.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a C header file, such as myfunctions.h

You can either include this as a separate file in your script, copy it to all of the load generators loadrunner\include directory (default search scope) or provide it in a network location which is accessible to all load generators