# Sharing function/action across multiple VuGen scripts run via Performance Center

Tags: javascript, loadrunner, vugen, hp-performance-center

I have few VuGen scripts that use Web/HTTP protocol using javascript. I am using VuGen 12.53 (patch 4). I have a login.js action that is common to all my scripts. Whenever there is a change to the login action, I have to make udpates to all the scripts. Instead I want to keep login in a common location and share the single action/function across all scripts.

I was able to achieve this using lr.loadLibrary() function when I replay on my local machine. I want to be able to do this when I run my scripts via HP Performance Center (all my scripts are saved on ALM). When I tried using the same lr.loadLibrary() function and run through perf center, I get the error that the file is not found.

Can someone please help me to figure out how to achieve this?

I have found this [Loadrunner - share common action between scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670742/loadrunner-share-common-action-between-scripts?rq=1), but it is for C. I need it for javascript.

Comment: Make sure that LoadRunner and Controller machine are same when you run in Performance Center. You will not face any issue in sharing the functions or actions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion naveen. Unfortunately I cannot do that - admin takes care of all that stuff.

Comment: The same approach for C can be used for JavaScript. Place the scripts in common LAN where all the controllers and load generators have the read access.

Answer (score 0):

Its an old post. Just sharing if anyone needs help with this yet.

If LG Agent is running as process, then the logged in user should have access to the shared path where the library is located. If its running as service, then ensure the shared path has given access to the local system account of each LG machine.

(You can see advance sharing option for the shared folder where you can add the LG host name, that will add the LG's system/service account. Then in the LG, go to services->LoadRunner agent service->Properties->LogOn->Allow Service to interact with desktop). The restart the agent service. With this setting LG's can access the shared drive paths while still running as Service.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @jjena. I use AWS loadgens that are spun up on demand. Since the LGs are not static (always on), I wouldn't be able to do this.